# Scope of Variable in While vs. For Loop

Tags: java, loops

I was wondering the following, given that I want to perform the same simple task but once using a while loop and once a for loop as follows:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i){
   sum += i;
}
```

I do not see any possibility to print out the (counting) variable `i` of the `for` loop while that would be no problem with a `while` loop:

```
int j = 0;
int sum2 = 0;    
while (j <= 6) {
    sum2 += j;
    ++j;
}
System.out.print(j);
```

Or is this possible using `for` loop too, somehow?

Comment: It's probably not too important, but which language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Just declare the loop variable outside the for loop:

```
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<=5;i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
```

Comment: One further question: Am I right that for(i=0;i<=5;i++) {..} and for(i=0;i<=5;++i) are the same thing?

Comment: Yes.  Since neither expression is being assigned to anything the i++ and ++i are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes thats possible. You just need to declare the variable `i` before the `for` loop. Try like this:-

```
int i; 
for (i=0; i<=5;i++) 
{ 
  sum += i; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually in some ways even easier for the for loop.

```
int i = 0;

for(;i <= 5; i++){

    sum += i;

}
```

Since you already declared the `int i = 0` you can skip the first entry in the for loop.